# Runtime error Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.String'

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project to generate a Microsoft word document. My code as follows. Im getting exception as "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.String'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.
   at reportexample.Form1.GetNewResult(Field wField, Document WordDoc) in F:\reportexample\reportexample\Form1.vb:line 114"

```
     Private Function GetNewResult(wField As Word.Field, WordDoc As Word.Document) As String

    Dim StopPos As Long
    Dim Variable As String = ""
    Dim UsedVariable As String
    Dim VariableValue As String
    Dim wRange As Word.Range

    Try
        Debug.Print(wField.Code)

        ' These three lines strip down the field code to find
        ' out it's name
        StopPos = InStrRev(wField.Code, "\*")
        Variable = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(wField.Code, StopPos - 3)
        Variable = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Variable, Len(Variable) - 14)
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString

    End Try


    ' Check this field hasn't already appeared in this
    ' document.
    If CheckUsedVariable(Variable) Then

        VariableValue = GetVariableValue(Variable)

    Else

        Select Case UCase(Variable)

            ' I don't simply want to insert a string -
            ' I wish to insert a table at the Product Field.
            Case "PRODUCT"

                ' Get the range (location) of the product field
                wRange = wField.Code
                ' Delete the field, as any text will be inserted into the
                ' {} of the existing field.
                wField.Delete()

                ' Enter our table information including headers.
                ' Ideally, I would get this data from an ADO recordset
                ' using GetString().
                With wRange

                    .Text = "PRODUCT" & vbTab & "CTSBATCHNO" & vbTab & "SUPP REF" & vbTab & "PACKNO" & vbTab & "STORAGE" & vbTab & "QTY UNITS" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3" & vbCrLf & _
                                "989797897" & vbTab & "hjhkhk" & vbTab & "kjhkjhkh" & vbTab & "kjhkjh" & vbTab & "Frozen" & vbTab & "3"

                    .FormattedText.Font.Name = "Arial"
                    .FormattedText.Font.Size = "8"

                    ' Once the data is there, we can convert it to a table
                    ' structure and format it to look pretty!
                    .ConvertToTable(vbTab, , , , WdTableFormat.wdTableFormatColorful2)

                End With


                ' Send back blank string as field does not exist anymore
                VariableValue = ""

            Case Else

                ' Get the value of the field from the user
                VariableValue = InputBox("Enter value for: " & Variable, "Value not recognised for Despatch Note!")
                AddNewVariable(Variable, VariableValue)

        End Select

    End If

    GetNewResult = VariableValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Word.Field.Code
```

is a `Range` object which cannot be converted to a string.

Try `wField.Code.Text`